# Why can we "from sqlalchemy import insert" when it is defined in "sql.alchemy.sql.expression"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, sqlalchemy, python-import

I recently saw a document on https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.insert.

I want to know why `insert()` is declared under `sqlalchemy.sql.expression`, and we can still import it by `from sqlalchemy import insert`.

Comment: Because that name is [explicitly imported in `sqlalchemy/__init__.py`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L53).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's defined here: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L53

`__init__.py` is a file that runs automatically whenever the folder is imported in Python.